# How to trigger vibration on Apple Watch OS 2?

Tags: xcode, swift2, apple-watch, audiotoolbox, watchos-2

I have been working with Apple Watch OS 2 for a while, but have not succeeded in triggering vibration on Apple Watch standalone app in Swift, using Xcode Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o).

All tutorials using vibration on iPhone in Swift look like:

```
 import AudioToolbox
 ...
 AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

But I cannot import the `AudioToolbox` library.

I get the error:

> Could not build Objective-C module "AudioToolbox"

Has anyone already found the way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean *"cannot import"*? Don't want to use (why not)? Get errors when you try (what errors)?

Comment: it sais No such module "AudioToolbox"

Comment: That is probably useful information to include *in the question*. Have you researched the error message?

Comment: and if i drag it into project it sais Could not build Objective/C module "AudioToolbox"

Comment: Again, *add that information to your question*.

Answer (score 14):

You can generate haptic & auditory feedback, using:

```
WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Click)
```

'Click' is one of the 'cases' (types of vibration/beeps) that you can choose, cfr:

```
enum WKHapticType : Int {  

case Notification  
case DirectionUp 
case DirectionDown  
case Success 
case Failure  
case Retry  
case Start  
case Stop  
case Click 
}
```

This only works on the device, not in the simulator.

Answer (score 7):

In **Swift 3:**

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.success)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a expert in **WatchKit** but I know that with **Watch OS 2** you can use:

```
WKInterfaceDevice().playHaptic(.Notification)
```

The function `playHaptic` called on a `WKInterfaceDevice` instance engage the haptic engine in Apple Watch.

See more in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/playHaptic:).

Answer (score 2):

The Correct format is

```
WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().playHaptic(.Notification)
```

You can easily play the notification sound on watch

Answer (score 1):

Function :

> WKInterfaceDevice().playHaptic(.Notification)

Here you have :
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceDevice/playHaptic:)

Answer (score 0):

```
WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.failure)
```

in Swift 3

Comment: As an inexperienced programmer myself I would much prefer an answer that gets straight to the point rather than a 500-word answer explaining functions and other stuff that the inexperienced programmer has no idea about. There this is my answer and is better than others because I get to the point.